# How can I change the properties of a UIViewController based on the action that switched to it?

Tags: ios, swift

In the app I'm writing, I have to show a lot of different pages with different text; I'd rather not use a lot of different views that are basically identical in structure.

My idea is that I have a single view for displaying text-only content, and programatically change the title (that shows in the nav bar) and the content based on the button that was pressed to open the view.

I can link the UITextView to a variable via @IBOutlet but I'm not sure how I can reference the view that's being loaded to change this.

Comment: How are you navigating between them? Is it a table view? Also, some code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

How about creating two properties for content and title in your destination controller and populate the values based on button click. Here is simple demo of this requirement.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

    self.addButtons()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Add Buttons

func addButtons() {

    var button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
    button1.setTitle("Content 1", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    button1.tag = 1
    button1.addTarget(self, action : "showContent:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button1)

    var button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 50))
    button2.setTitle("Content 2", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    button2.tag = 2
    button2.addTarget(self, action : "showContent:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button2)
}

func showContent(sender: UIButton!) {
    var displayContentController = DisplayContentController()

    switch (sender.tag) {
    case 1:
        displayContentController.content = "Test Content 1"
        displayContentController.titleText = "Content1"
        break;

    case 2:
        displayContentController.content = "Test Content 2"
        displayContentController.titleText = "Content2"
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    self.presentViewController(displayContentController, animated: true,completion: nil)
}
```

}

class DisplayContentController: UIViewController {

```
var contentView:UITextView?
var titleLabel:UILabel?
var content: String?
var titleText: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.addTextView()
    self.addTitleLabel()

    titleLabel?.text = titleText
    contentView?.text = content

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK:- Add UILabel

func addTitleLabel() {

    titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 5, width: 100, height: 50))
    titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(titleLabel!)
}


//MARK:- Add UITextView

func addTextView() {

    contentView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 60, width: 250, height: 250))
    self.view.addSubview(contentView!)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using segues in storyboard, you can cast `segue`'s `destinationController` as the type of view controller that you have and pass information to it.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let someViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SomeViewController
    someViewController.someProperty = someValue
}
```